# Awk: loop & save different lines to different files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm looping over a series of large files with a shell script:

```
i=0
while read line
do

    # get first char of line
    first=`echo "$line" | head -c 1`

    # make output filename
    name="$first"
    if [ "$first" = "," ]; then
        name='comma'
    fi
    if [ "$first" = "." ]; then
        name='period'
    fi

    # save line to new file
    echo "$line" >> "$2/$name.txt"

    # show live counter and inc
    echo -en "\rLines:\t$i"
    ((i++))

done <$file
```

The first character in each line will either be alphanumeric, or one of the above defined characters (which is why I'm renaming them for use in the output file name).

**It's way too slow.**

5,000 lines takes 128seconds.

At this rate I've got a solid month of processing.

**Will awk be faster here?**

If so, how do I fit the logic into awk?

Comment: `$[]` is deprecated, use `((i++))` or `((i += 1))`. Also, when you `echo` a variable (and most other times you use a variable), you should quote it: `echo "$LINE"`. And it's best to use lower case or mixed case variable names to avoid potential name collision with shell or environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can certainly be done more efficiently in bash.

To give you an example: `echo foo | head` does a `fork()` call, creates a subshell, sets up a pipeline, starts the external `head` program... and there's no reason for it at all.

If you want the first character of a line, without any inefficient mucking with subprocesses, it's as simple as this:

```
c=${line:0:1}
```

I would also seriously consider sorting your input, so you can only re-open the output file when a new first character is seen, rather than every time through the loop.

That is -- preprocess with sort (as by replacing `<$file` with `< <(sort "$file")`) and do the following each time through the loop, reopening the output file only conditionally:

```
if [[ $name != "$current_name" ]] ; then
  current_name="$name"
  exec 4>>"$2/$name" # open the output file on FD 4
fi
```

...and then append to the open file descriptor:

```
printf '%s\n' "$line" >&4
```

(not using echo because it can behave undesirably if your line is, say, `-e` or `-n`).

Alternately, if the number of possible output files is small, you can just open them all on different FDs up-front (substituting other, higher numbers where I chose `4`), and conditionally output to one of those pre-opened files. Opening and closing files is expensive -- each `close()` forces a flush to disk -- so this should be a substantial help.

Comment: Don't you want a newline? `printf '%s\n' "$line" >&4`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    punctlist = ", . ? ! - '"
    pnamelist = "comma period question_mark exclamation_mark hyphen apostrophe"
    pcount = split(punctlist, puncts)
    ncount = split(pnamelist, pnames)
    if (pcount != ncount) {print "error: counts don't match, pcount:", pcount, "ncount:", ncount; exit}
    for (i = 1; i <= pcount; i++) {
        punct_lookup[puncts[i]] = pnames[i]
    }
}
{
    print > punct_lookup[substr($0, 1, 1)] ".txt"
    printf "\r%6d", i++
}
END {
    printf "\n"
}
```

The `BEGIN` block builds an associative array so you can do `punct_lookup[","]` and get "comma".

The main block simply does the lookups for the filenames and outputs the line to the file. In AWK, `>` truncates the file the first time and appends subsequently. If you have existing files that you don't want truncated, then change it to `>>` (but don't use `>>` otherwise).

Comment: Does awk cache file handles, or is this doing a new pair of open() and close() calls on each line?

Comment: I just `strace`d it and it opens (and keeps open) separate file descriptors for each file. Actually, it seems to cache the writes in a 4K buffer.

Comment: Nice, then -- I hate to see pure-bash solutions needlessly ruled out, but this should have decent performance too.

Comment: Since the `punct_lookup` is pretty small, it would be more maintainable to just write it out: `punct_lookup[","] = "comma"; punct_lookup["."] = "period"; ...`

Answer (score 2):

A few things to speed it up:

1. Don't use echo/head to get the first character. You're
       spawning at least two additional processes per line. Instead,
       use bash's parameter expansion facilities to get the first character.
2. Use if-elif to avoid checking `$first` against all the
   possibilities
       each time. Even better, if you are using bash 4.0 or later, use an associative array
       to store the output file names, rather than checking against
       `$first` in a big if-statement for each line.
3. If you don't have a version of bash that supports associative
   arrays, replace your if statements with the following.

   ```
   if [[ "$first" = "," ]]; then
       name='comma'
   elif [[ "$first" = "." ]]; then
       name='period'
   else
       name="$first"
   fi
   ```

But the following is suggested. Note the use of `$REPLY` as the default variable used by `read` if no name is given (just FYI).

```
declare -A OUTPUT_FNAMES
output[","]=comma
output["."]=period
output["?"]=question_mark
output["!"]=exclamation_mark
output["-"]=hyphen
output["'"]=apostrophe
i=0
while read
do

    # get first char of line
    first=${REPLY:0:1}

    # make output filename
    name=${output[$first]:-$first}

    # save line to new file
    echo $REPLY >> "$name.txt"

    # show live counter and inc
    echo -en "\r$i"
    ((i++))

done <$file
```

Comment: Point of convention -- upper-case names are conventional only for environment variables or built-ins, not for regular, internal-shell variables. Also, you're re-opening the output file each time through the loop, which is going to be much more expensive than calculating its name.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's what I was using in my original code, until Dennis pointed it out and I changed it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: good points. I'll change the variable names; I'll defer to your code for the point about sorting and opening files when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another take:

```
declare -i i=0
declare -A names
while read line; do
    first=${line:0:1}
    if [[ -z ${names[$first]} ]]; then
        case $first in
            ,) names[$first]="$2/comma.txt" ;;
            .) names[$first]="$2/period.txt" ;;
            *) names[$first]="$2/$first.txt" ;;
        esac
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "${names[$first]}"
    printf "\rLine $((++i))"
done < "$file"
```

and

```
awk -v dir="$2" '
    {
        first = substr($0,1,1)
        if (! (first in names)) {
            if (first == ",")      names[first] = dir "/comma.txt"
            else if (first == ".") names[first] = dir "/period.txt"
            else                   names[first] = dir "/" first ".txt"
        }
        print > names[first]
        printf("\rLine %d", NR)
    }
'
```